# How to avoid uicollectionview deselect all items when new snapshot is applied?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, snapshot

When I call `dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)`, the related UICollectionView deselects all cells.

This is a problem when receiving new data in the background as, when this change is commited, the user sees its current selection disappear.

How to avoid deselection of all collection items when `apply(snapshot: animatingDifferences)` is called ?

Comment: Obviously a lot depends on what you are doing to indicate selection to the user.

Comment: @matt - the cell background is drawn in a different color. As a matter of fact I use UIBackgroundConfiguration, but I don't think that's relevant. Before apply(snapshot:) the UICollectionView selection is not empty, after the call, it is.

Comment: Of course it's relevant. The thing to think to yourself here is that the notion of selection is properly _data_ based, not _row_ based. You have somehow set up code that colors the background. That code needs to be conscious of whether this data is the selected data.

Comment: I took some time to think about it, but I think I'll keep a different opinion. Selection information shouldn't be part of the model. I could accept that it is somewhere between the model and the view, but that poses the problem of keeping that information in synch with the list of selected index pathes kept inside the collection view. I found the root cause of the problem (see answer), and it is not related. Anyway, I thank you for your trying to help. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found the root of the problem, and it lies inside Apple's code. At a minimum, I'd call that an "undocumented feature", some might say it's a bug.

When a snapshot is applied, the behavior of the `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` differs, whether the `ItemIdentifierType` is a value-type or a reference-type.

Of course, your `ItemIdentifierType` must conform to `Hashable`, but when calling `apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)`:

- If `ItemIdentifierType` is a value-type (struct), then, its `==`and `hash` functions are called, in order to compare the items of the newly received snapshot to the items of the currently shown snapshot, which allows to find the diff, animate differenes, and keep the selection if any (which was the original problem I asked help for).
- If `ItemIdentifierType` is a reference-type (class), then, its `==`and `hash` function are **not** called, which means that the items of the new snapshot and the currently shown snapshot are compare with bare reference equality (are pointers equal). As a consequence, if you have built your items "from scratch" with new instances having the same hash, then the comparison is always false, and you don't get the animations, and you loose the selection.

One easy work-around in this situation is to encapsulate your reference-type into a struct, which will forward `==` and `hash` to the class ones, and use this struct as the `ItemIdentifierType`